# Regex to match string with optional section preceded by space

Tags: regex

I need help figuring out how to match a string that will have optional sections. The issue is that the optional section will be prefixed by a space and `<` and suffixed by `>`.
This is what I have currently

```
^([\\w,:\\s.]+)\\s-\\s<([A-Z]+)>\\s<([\\s\\w-]+)>\\s<([\\w-]+)>(\\s<[\\d.]+>)?(\\s<[\\d]+>)?\\s<([\\w.]+)>\\s-\\s<(.+?(?=>$|$))
```

This is the string I am trying to match

```
Jul 09, 2022 03:05:12.570 AM - <DEBUG> <Default Executor-thread-26> <logging-poc> <100.99.88.1> <123456> <myco> - <Inside getDebugLog()>
```

The section `(\\s<[\\d.]+>)?` and `(\\s<[\\d]+>)?` correspond to the ip address and account. As it is currently, the match ends up including the space and `< >`.

```
Record map{logdatetime=Jul 09, 2022 03:05:12.570 AM, severity=DEBUG, thread=Default Executor-thread-26, application=logging-poc, ip= <100.99.88.1>, account= <123456>, module=myco, message=Inside getDebugLog()>}
```

I only want the value for the ip and the account like below

```
Record map{logdatetime=Jul 09, 2022 03:05:12.570 AM, severity=DEBUG, thread=Default Executor-thread-26, application=logging-poc, ip=100.99.88.1, account=123456, module=myco, message=Inside getDebugLog()>}
```

The pattern should also work for this line of log (where the optional sections have been removed)

```
Jul 09, 2022 03:05:12.570 AM - <DEBUG> <Default Executor-thread-26> <logging-poc> <myco> - <Inside getDebugLog()>
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is my first post .. looks like SO randomly bolded some of the text. And also the last line of log looks different from what I had posted. I tried editing as well

Comment: The bolding is because of the lines with `----`. That's used to mark a section heading.

Comment: Your input looks like XML, have you considered using an XML parser?

Comment: @Rogue, it is just a line of log

Comment: You should ensure you are excluding the spaces `\\s` and carets `<`,`>` from the capturing group `(...)`. So `(\\s<[\\d.]+>)` should be `\\s<([\\d.]+)>`. I think you may have more than one instance of this.

Comment: @GoldenLion, I have given examples of values parsed out of the current pattern and also an example of how it should be parsed out. To elaborate, I want to just parse out the ip address and the account (in the adjacent section) excluding the space and < >. But these two sections including the space and < > are by themselves optional

Comment: @Rogue, the two sections are different in that one allows a . while the second one does not

Comment: @shyamala The advice stands for both sections. I'm writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your 5th and 6th capturing groups.

- 5th group: `(\s<[\d.]+>)?`
- 6th group: `(\s<[\d]+>)?`

These will capture the surrounding spaces and `<`/`>`. The solution is to capture the information you desire in a subgroup:

- 5th (and now 6th) group: `(\s<([\d.]+)>)?`
- The now-7th (and 8th) group: `(\s<([\d]+)>)?`

The old group 7 is now group 9, and the old group 8 is now group 10.

Per your comments below, since you need to keep the same group indices, you can make use of a *non-capturing group*, using the syntax `(?:pattern)`.

- 5th group (inner parenthesis): `(?:\s<([\d.]+)>)?`
- 6th group (inner parenthesis): `(?:\s<([\d]+)>)?`

The end-result regex (using Java escapes):

```
^([\\w,:\\s.]+)\\s-\\s<([A-Z]+)>\\s<([\\s\\w-]+)>\\s<([\\w-]+)>\\s(?:<([\\d.]+)>)?(?:\\s<([\\d]+)>)?\\s<([\\w.]+)>\\s-\\s<(.+?(?=>$|$))
```

This will **not** change the indices of the groups you have captured, and will allow you to capture only the parts that you are interested in, while still being able to denote the outer group as optional (via `()?`).

Comment: Thank you for the response. The pattern works for the string which contains the optional elements however does not work for the string that does not. There is also another issue that we have to keep the group numbers intact .. Like you mentioned, we now have 10 groups instead of 8. The groups correspond to the data that is being parsed out of it. Some back story on this pattern, this will be used in the kinesis agent configuration and pushed to Opensearch (log aggregation) and having more groups than that will muddle up the data being aggregated

Comment: I tried to use the | to create a pattern containing two pattern sets (one for strings that contain the optional sections and one for strings that do not). However that isn't working as expected.

Comment: ^(?:(([\\w,:\\s.]+)\\s-\\s<([A-Z]+)>\\s<([\\s\\w-]+)>\\s<([\\w-]+)>\\s<([\\d.]+)>\\s<([\\d]+)>\\s<([\\w.]+)>\\s-\\s<(.+?(?=>$|$))))|(?:(([\\w,:\\s.]+)\\s-\\s<([A-Z]+)>\\s<([\\s\\w-]+)>\\s<([\\w-]+)>\\s<([\\w.]+)>\\s-\\s<(.+?(?=>$|$))))

Comment: It may be until tomorrow that I can look at this a little closer - today got quite busy for me. However, a quick (and honestly proper) solution would be to use _named_ groups, such that you can always specify which group is associated with which name, and then the indices of the groups do not matter.

Comment: I would still like to know if there is a "pattern only" way without modifying the grouping, however I figured out an alternate way to address this issue. I ended up separating the patterns for the two scenarios in the config file for the kinesis agent.

Comment: There is, if you use a non-capturing group via `(?:pattern)`. I'll update my answer in just a moment.